# What ratio of processes and threads should my web server have?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, puma

If I'm running a Ruby app backed by a web server like Puma, which lets you combine processes and threads, what is the number of each I should use? Assuming that my code is of course thread safe (and I'm running a Ruby implementation which supports native threads). Of couse, I'm not asking for specific numbers, just general ratios which theoretically perform better than others.

If threads are much faster, because they use little memory, then shouldn't I only use threads? But then again, I heard that hybrid models (combinations of threads and processes) is the best way to go. I also heard that I should match number of processes with the number of cores; is that true?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not what you want to hear, but: **It depends.** Even giving a ratio is kind of hand-wavy, I think. There are a lot of variables that can influence the performance (HW probably being the biggest: RAM, number of cores etc.).

I faced a "similar question" where I wanted to find out what number of unicorn workers (application workers) and nginx workers would be the best for my application (and what an impact caching would have).

The best way I found to answer that sort of question was to run some benchmarks. Here is more or less what I did:

I wrote a script which ran [apache bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) (`ab`) 3 times on a number of urls I wanted to test.

```
function run_apache_bench() {
  ab -n $N -c $C -g "results/${ID}/root_${1}.tsv"  url1
  ab -n $N -c $C -g "results/${ID}/index_${1}.tsv" url2
  ab -n $N -c $C -g "results/${ID}/show_${1}.tsv" url3
}
```

On a different docker containers with different numbers of workers. (On identical hardware which was used in production.) I then plotted the results with gnuplot and got something like this:

Example with 2 unicorn workers and 1 nginx worker:

[image]

Example with 4 unicorn workers and 4 nginx workers:

[image]

Bonus example: Here is the dramatic performance improvement with enabling "russian doll caching" :)

[image]

But I want to point out some gotchas:

- I did not measure memory useage
- Apache bench does not "trigger" javascript/css requests (assets), which means I was basically just measuring html rendering.
- It was a pain in the butt to set the benchmarks up (automate container building etc)

Hope that helps you out.